# How to use thor actions from bundle console?

Tags: ruby, bundler, thor

Some times I use `bundle console` to load a console with the project's dependencies and test API usage.

So my question is: how can I test [thor's actions](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/wycats/thor/master/Thor/Shell/Basic) like [ask](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/wycats/thor/Thor/Shell/Basic#ask-instance_method) from a bundler console?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a gemspec file with `thor` dependency in it, you can use bundler's console.

```
cat limarka.gemspec

(...)

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  (...)
  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.12"
  (...)
  spec.add_dependency "thor"
  (...)
end
```

When you type `bundle console` it will load all gem dependencies into a console for you:

```
$ bundle console
Resolving dependencies...
```

Now to run a thor's action, you will need to create an instance of the class that contains the action. The `ask` action is from `Thor::Shell::Basic`, so here's the code to call it:

```
irb(main):001:0> city = Thor::Shell::Basic.new.ask "Type name of your city:"
Type name of your city: João Pessoa
=> "João Pessoa"
irb(main):002:0> city
=> "João Pessoa"
irb(main):003:0>
```